# C Code: Efficient way to parse through to end of LinkedList

Tags: c, parsing, linked-list

I have a Struct Data, this will be a Linked List of Messages. For every new message, I need to append at the last in linked List. I have a Counter where I know how many messages are present.
Instead of parsing till the end of the linked List. Is there any better way to get to the specific position in Linked List??

```
struct Data {
   char            *message;
   struct Data     *next;
}data;

int total_message;
```

Right now I am parsing like below:

```
struct Data *traverse;

while(traverse->next != NULL)
    traverse = traverse->next;
```

I tried below as well, I am not sure why this wrong logically it seems right to me.

```
data[total_messages - 1].next = new_data;
```

Is there any better way other than storing pointer to Last Message?

Answer (score 5):

Consider maintaining a pointer to the tail of the linked list.

```
data * head = NULL;
data * tail = NULL;
void Append(data * entry) {
  if (!head) {
    head = entry;
  }
  if (tail) {
    tail->next = entry;
  }
  tail = entry;
}
```

Why traversing (as in the question) is bad?

If we maintain only the `head` and the number of messages say `n`, then for each append we have to traverse the `n` linked nodes starting from `head` -- that's `O(n)` operation -- slightly inefficient. If adding to the tail of the list is a frequent operation -- as it seems in your case -- then maintaining the tail pointer is efficient. Space wise, maintaining a counter is same as maintaining a pointer.

Why the following is bad?

```
data[total_messages - 1].next = new_data;
```

That's an array notation. Arrays are contiguous block of memory. In linked list, the nodes could be anywhere in memory, they cannot be accessed in array notation like that.

Comment: Was gonna say the same thing.  Either replacing, or in addition to total_message.

Comment: Thank you...I thought of that way. I am just curious can I go to end of LL using no of message. Instead of a separate pointer.
I have various LL of Messages, Maintaining end pointer for each is a Huge List.

Comment: I don't think so; that's what arrays are for.

Comment: @KaushikKoneru: If you maintain the number of messages as say `n`, then you have to traverse the `n` linked nodes starting from `head` -- that's `O(n)` operation -- slightly inefficient. If adding to the tail of the list is a frequent operation -- as it seems in your case -- then maintaining the tail pointer is efficient. Space wise, maintaining a counter is same as maintaining a pointer.

Comment: @chqrlie mako explained in below comment.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that traversing a very large linked list can wipe out your memory cache, leading to poor performance in other areas.  In some cases, you may wish to construct your lists in reverse (push front) and then reverse them later (which is a single O(N) operation).  But keeping a tail pointer is so trivial, it's crazy not to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` syntax works for arrays because arrays arrange their data in a line, in a predictable way. Linked lists do not. You can only find out where the ith element is by following the `next` pointers.

`data[i]` refers to the data `i` places after the memory address `data`, which is unlikely to be at the location of a Data struct. Writing data to that position will generally just disrupt a random section of code somewhere else in the program.

Answer (score 1):

A fast and relatively simple solution is to push each new element onto the *front* of the list while parsing, and then reverse the list in place once you have pushed all the elements.